# Unable to Reinstall Windows

Tags: partitioning

Love Ubuntu but it's way over my head to use. Can't reinstall Windows 7 as the MS os disk informs me that I do not have NTFS. I truly have read many answers on Ubuntu help but again, way over my head. **Would someone be able to give me the easiest way to accomplish this task of getting Win 7 back?** I previously had Windows and used Ubuntu as a boot selection on start-up and that was a better way for me to attempt to learn Ubuntu. I'd like to go back to that. TMI perhaps but I'm a pretty old guy with almost no understanding of computers and definitely can't afford a trip to a computer store. Any help and your patience would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "reinstall" windows if you do not have it currently on an ntfs partition. If your media allows you a fresh install, do that and you'll have to choose a custom install to choose / reformat a partition for it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the problem.

let me try to help you understand what really happened. Windows and Linux use different formatting systems to get installed so when you removed *windows* you changed or reformatted the *hard disk*. So to get it back you will need to reformat (as it were) the disk back to *what Windows* can understand.

That being said you will need a *windows recovery disk* to do this and a lot of **patience**. Please see this [excellent article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on) to do that and always come back to ask for more help if you get stuck